# Recreate jQuery's slideUp and slideDown, but for slideRight and slideLeft instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using slideUp and slideDown to animate sections hiding and showing using AngularJS's ngShow. It works fine, but I'd much rather have slideLeft and slideRight. How would I go about recreating slideUp and slideDown for those?

slideUp automatically hides the the element and slideDown automatically shows it - how would I be able to configure this such that they hide and show when I want then to? e.g.:

`$(element).slideLeftAndHide();
$(element).slideLeftAndShow();`

As opposed to

`$(element).slideUp(); // $element.slideUpAndHide();`

Comment: With jQuery animate function http://api.jquery.com/animate/ or just with plain css animation stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged Angular.js, I assume you're also using Angular. You should prefer using something like `ng-class` instead of literally showing and hiding elements with jQuery. This is a good, modular way to do what you want using existing Angular.js capabilities and fast CSS animations.

I also assume that you're doing the show/hide part in response to some sort of conditional value changing, is that right?

If so, to start off:

1. When the conditional value changes, let the DOM know by adding a class name when a condition turns true.

```
<div ng-class="{showing: myDataFinallyLoaded}">...</div>
```

In this case, if `myDataFinallyLoaded` is true, the div has a `showing` class attached.

2. When the div has a `showing` class name attached, animate it into view.

```
div {
    transform: translate(-100%) scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
}

div.showing {
    /* Any CSS rules can go in here! */
    transform: translate(0px) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

3. When your condition becomes true, update the scope.

```
someRandomAPI.loadEverything().then(function() {
  $scope.myDataFinallyLoaded = true;
});
```

Comment: This seems to be working, however how would I get the divs to sit on the same row when they're showing/hiding? Currently each div occupies its own row until the div above it has hidden completely, then it moves upwards.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the showing/hiding is for transferring the view between two divs - one hides, the other shows

Comment: Maybe Angular has a way to make whatever you're trying to accomplish better... could you describe your usecase a bit more? Maybe something like `ng-repeat` or a directive could help here. (If you aren't looking for a very general solution, simply doing `showing: !myDataFinallyLoaded` in the other div's ng-class attribute could work.)

Comment: I've rigged up a [little JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jd23mda/) that shows what I'm doing well enough. For some reason the transitions aren't working and I'm not really sure why. Everything else is fine, though

Comment: You're doing `display: none` immediately when the class is applied. This hides the element before transitions have a chance to pop in. Also, they are still flowing below each other because the left-right movement is simply movement of the rendered pixels, not the DOM element itself. You can fix that by positioning them absolutely, for example.

Comment: Set the position on the hidden classes to absolute, set the position to the visible class to relative. Transitions animates "left" and "opacity" properties. It's a little messy, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to achieve this:

```
$('#element').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, "fast");
```